# Nodeunit Execution Order?

Tags: node.js, nodeunit

I am trying to test my web server using nodeunit:

test.js

```
exports.basic = testCase({

  setUp: function (callback) {
    this.ws = new WrappedServer();
    this.ws.run(PORT);
    callback();
  },

  tearDown: function (callback) {
    delete this.ws;
    callback();
  },

  testFoo: function(test) { 
    var socket = ioClient.connect(URL);
    console.log('before client emit')
    socket.emit('INIT', 1, 1);
    console.log('after client emit');
  }
});
```

and this is my very simple nodejs server:

```
WrappedServer.prototype.run = function(port) { 
  this.server = io.listen(port, {'log level': 2});
  this.attachCallbacks();
};

WrappedServer.prototype.attachCallbacks = function() { 
  var ws = this;    
  ws.server.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) { 
    ws.attachDebugToSocket(socket);

    console.log('socket attaching INIT');
    socket.on('INIT', function(userId, roomId) {
      // do something here
    });
    console.log('socket finished attaching INIT');
  });
}
```

Basically I am getting this error:

```
[...cts/lolol/nodejs/testing](testingServer)$ nodeunit ws.js 
   info  - socket.io started
before client emit
after client emit
   info  - handshake authorized 1013616781193777373
The "sys" module is now called "util". It should have a similar interface.
socket before attaching INIT
socket finished attaching INIT
   info  - transport end
```

Somehow, the socket emits INIT BEFORE the server attaches callbacks for sockets.

Why is this happening? In addition, what's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you were expecting the order to be this?

- socket before attaching INIT
- socket finished attaching INIT
- before client emit
- after client emit

From the small amount of code given, the issue is probably two things.

First, and probably the main issue, is that your ioClient.connect will not connect immediately. You need to pass some kind of callback to that, and emit `INIT`, and then execute the test's `callback` function once it has actually connected.

Second, you should probably do the same thing with you `run` command. `listen` will not stary listening immediately, so you're going to get inconsistent results occasionally if it hasn't started listening by the time it executes your test. You should also pass the setUp's `callback` to `io.listen`.

**Update**

To be clear for `listen`, just like most things in node, the socketio server's `listen` method is asynchronous. Calling the method tells it to start listening, but there is some time in the background where the server sets up the networking stuff to start listening. Just like node's core `listen`, http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#server.listen, socket.io's version takes a callback argument that is called once the server is up and listening.

```
io.listen(port, {'log level': 2}, callback);
```

Unless socket.io starts giving you errors about failing to connect, this probably is not an issue, but it is something to keep in mind. Treating asynchronous actions as if they were instantaneous is an easy way to make bugs that only come up occasionally. Since your `run` wraps listen, I think in general, not just for testing, passing a callback to `run` would be a very good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup. Concerning "You should also pass the setUp's callback to io.listen" What do you mean by that? As far as io.listen doesn't really take a callback. Even if it does, this means I will be injecting code from my test file to my actual server?